# Why it is a distinguished triangle?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

The following paper gives an alternative formulation of the definition of epaisee subcategory:
http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022404989900819/1-s2.0-0022404989900819-main.pdf?_tid=76c221e6-7282-11e6-afcb-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1472981714_a8d233643dcc094e8f98bf3ff4b81986

Can anyone tell me in the proof of proposition 1.3, why the sequence $X_2 [-1] \rightarrow X_1 \rightarrow X \rightarrow $ is a distinguished triangle?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a general and well-known fact about triangulated categories that for any objects $X_1$ and $X_2$,
$$X_2[-1]\to X_1\to X_1\oplus X_2\to X_2$$
is a distinguished triangle, where the first map is the zero map and the other maps are the obvious ones.

You can find a complete proof in Neeman's "Triangulated Categories", Corollary 1.2.7, but the proof is quite straightforward.

Sketch: complete the zero map $X_2[-1]\to X_1$ to a distinguished triangle
$$X_2[-1]\to X_1\to Y\to X_2$$
and consider the long exact sequences obtained by applying the cohomological functors $\text{Hom}(X_2,-)$ and $\text{Hom}(-,X_1)$ to this triangle.

Comment: @ Jeremy Rickard Get it.Thank you.